# How can Save API respond (For each order request - PDF file) with order id in database?

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status, event-observer

I create event with observer and execute it . In execute function I get API respond (PDF file) for each order request . How can save this pdf link with order id in table I create it (Install schema) ?

Comment: You want to save the link in an order? You may need to create an order attribute. If this is the way you go, I can answer you.

Comment: Great idea you mean Create EAV then ??

Comment: Yes you're right. Are you sure you want to go this way?

Comment: yes why not ? you have another idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you the answer into 3 parts:

1. Create Order Attribute
2. Set the order attribute
3. Show the PDF link in admin order page

**Create Order Attribute**

For creating order attribute, you MUST use setup script with the following code:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    protected $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    protected $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup $quoteInstaller */
            $quoteInstaller = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'quote_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup $salesInstaller */
            $salesInstaller = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

            //Add attributes to quote
            $entityAttributesCodes = [
                'pdf_file_link' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            ];

            foreach ($entityAttributesCodes as $code => $type) {
                $quoteInstaller->addAttribute('quote', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length' => 255, 'visible' => true, 'nullable' => true,]);
                $salesInstaller->addAttribute('order', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length' => 255, 'visible' => true, 'nullable' => true,]);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Set the order attribute**

You said you created an observer, so in your observer file, add this code:

```
$order->setData("pdf_file_link", $url);
```

**Show the PDF link in admin order page**

Create file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Add the content below in anywhere you like:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($order->getData("pdf_file_link")) ?>
```

Comment: okay let me test today and back to you .

Comment: *Order Attribute - you forget } for class. also something wrong i cant find attrbiute in database .

Comment: You can look at table sales_order. You should have a new attribute at the end.

Comment: Sure i already look at it

Comment: Did you enable the module after saving the setup script?

Comment: sure I already test module and create order to get details in email . all done but still cant find new attribute

Comment: I know the reason: I use upgrade script in this example. So set the module version to 1.0.1